# Renomear arquivos em massa a partir de uma lista do bloco de notas

Tags: python-3.x

Preciso renomear muitas (muitas!!!) fotos dentro de algumas pastas, pra isso decidi utilizar o método *os.rename* dentro de um laço a partir de uma lista auxiliar no bloco de notas que contém em cada linha o nome antigo da foto, e um ponto e vírgula separando para qual é o nome novo de cada uma.

Exemplo de como está o **bloco de notas**:

```
*nomeantigo1;nomenovo1*

*nomeantigo2;nomenovo2*

*nomeantigo3;nomenovo3*
```

A princípio o código roda certinho substituindo os nomes, principalmente em pastas menores com poucas fotos. Mas em pastas maiores ele começa a rodar parcialmente e às vezes nem roda!

Não sei se é algum erro de lógica no loop ou de alguma permissão do sistema!

Como são muitos arquivos estou rodando o código direto no HD externo, e utilizando Python 3.6.5 no Windows 10

**Meu código:**

```
import os
import string
import re
from os import rename
from os import replace
from os import listdir

lista_principal = os.listdir('.')
arquivo = open('lista_auxiliar.txt')
sublista = [linha.strip() for linha in arquivo]
arquivo.close()

nome_antigo = list()
nome_novo = list()
nomeacoes = list()
nomeacoes_separadas = list()

for i in range(len(sublista)):
    nomeacoes.append(sublista[i].split(';'))

for i in range(len(nomeacoes)):
    if (type(nomeacoes[i]) is list):
        nomeacoes_separadas = nomeacoes[i];
        nome_antigo.append(nomeacoes_separadas[0])
        nome_novo.append(nomeacoes_separadas[1])

for nome in lista_principal:
    nome_tratado = nome.split('.jpg')
    nome_tratado_teste = str(nome_tratado[0])
    for i in range(len(nome_antigo)):
        if nome_tratado_teste == nome_antigo[i]:
            os.rename(nome, str(nome_novo[i]) + '.jpg')
```

Desculpem se a lógica não for muito limpa, sou iniciante em programação!

Agradeço desde já

Comment: Os nomes dos arquivos que estão nesse txt são de um mesmo diretório?

Comment: sim, estou rodando tudo no mesmo diretório!

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem, o que você precisa fazer é apenas:

```
import os

with open('nomes.txt') as nomes:
    for nome in nomes:
        antigo, novo = nome.strip().split(';')
        os.rename(antigo, novo)
        print(f'Arquivo {antigo} renomeado para {novo}')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SharpKindheartedDecimal)</sup>

Isto é, percorre todas as linhas do arquivo que possui os nomes dos arquivos e renomeia um a um.

Comment: Seu código tá mais limpo e curto, mas continua dando no mesmo resultado que o meu! (o meu tratava as extensões do arquivo também)

Agora eu vi que ele para de renomear quando acha na lista um arquivo que já foi renomeado ou não está na mesma pasta, pois rodo o mesmo script e mesma lista em diversas pastas, está tudo em um só.

Saberia me dizer como faço pro laço continuar rodando mesmo depois de dar um "erro" de "arquivo X não encontrado na pasta"?